# ng-selected with true or false

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

Hi I have a select options like following.

```
[
  {
    "value": "India",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "value": "Nepal",
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "value": "Bhutan",
    "selected": false
  }
]

<select name="{{key}}" >
<option id="{{item.value}}" ng-selected="item.selected"  ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

I have to send same options to server which is selected/un-selected. Can any one suggest how ?

Now I can show and selected value also, but I am not able to catch, If user changes.

If user selects Nepal then have to look like and except Nepal all are false.
    {
      "value": "Nepal",
      "selected": true
    }

Some times it is multi select also.

Thanks in Advance,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.value}}" ng-selected="item.selected == true">{{item.value}}
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Fraction, There is no change in selected value after selecting another country also. If user selects Nepal then have to look like and except Nepal all are false. { "value": "Nepal", "selected": true }

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ng-model in select attribute.

```
<select ng-model="country">
```